# How can I statically link my project dependencies using vcpkg with Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors, static-linking, vcpkg

I've read some ways to do what I want but none of them worked and they end up using the same method.

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58506430/how-to-statically-link-vcpkg-produced-lib-file-in-visual-studio), which I couldn't make it work...

Here's what I get outputed:

```
1>libcurl.lib(memdebug.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_accept
1>libcurl.lib(memdebug.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_closesocket
1>libcurl.lib(memdebug.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_recv
1>libcurl.lib(memdebug.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_send
1>libcurl.lib(memdebug.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_socket
1>libcurl.lib(multi.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSACloseEvent
1>libcurl.lib(telnet.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSACloseEvent
1>libcurl.lib(multi.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSACreateEvent
1>libcurl.lib(telnet.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSACreateEvent
1>libcurl.lib(multi.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAEnumNetworkEvents
1>libcurl.lib(telnet.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAEnumNetworkEvents
1>libcurl.lib(multi.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAEventSelect
1>libcurl.lib(telnet.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAEventSelect
1>libcurl.lib(multi.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAResetEvent
1>libcurl.lib(multi.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSASetEvent
1>libcurl.lib(multi.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAWaitForMultipleEvents
1>libcurl.lib(ftp.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAGetLastError
1>libcurl.lib(telnet.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAGetLastError
1>libcurl.lib(tftp.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAGetLastError
1>libcurl.lib(asyn-thread.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAGetLastError
1>libcurl.lib(sendf.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAGetLastError
1>libcurl.lib(connect.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAGetLastError
1>libcurl.lib(schannel.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAGetLastError
1>libcurl.lib(select.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __WSAFDIsSet
1>libcurl.lib(select.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_select
1>libcurl.lib(select.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSASetLastError
1>libcurl.lib(connect.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSASetLastError
1>libcurl.lib(curl_addrinfo.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSASetLastError
1>libcurl.lib(connect.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_bind
1>libcurl.lib(ftp.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_bind
1>libcurl.lib(tftp.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_bind
1>libcurl.lib(socketpair.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_bind
1>libcurl.lib(connect.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_connect
1>libcurl.lib(socketpair.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_connect
1>libcurl.lib(connect.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_getpeername
1>libcurl.lib(socketpair.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_getpeername
1>libcurl.lib(connect.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_getsockname
1>libcurl.lib(ftp.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_getsockname
1>libcurl.lib(socketpair.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_getsockname
1>libcurl.lib(connect.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_getsockopt
1>libcurl.lib(telnet.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_htons
1>libcurl.lib(curl_addrinfo.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_htons
1>libcurl.lib(doh.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_htons
1>libcurl.lib(socks_sspi.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_htons
1>libcurl.lib(connect.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_htons
1>libcurl.lib(hostip.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_htons
1>libcurl.lib(ftp.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_htons
1>libcurl.lib(smb.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_htons
1>libcurl.lib(connect.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ntohs
1>libcurl.lib(ftp.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ntohs
1>libcurl.lib(socks_sspi.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ntohs
1>libcurl.lib(connect.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_setsockopt
1>libcurl.lib(transfer.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_setsockopt
1>libcurl.lib(socketpair.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_setsockopt
1>libcurl.lib(connect.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAIoctl
1>libcurl.lib(transfer.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAIoctl
1>libcurl.lib(urlapi.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_inet_pton
1>libcurl.lib(curl_addrinfo.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_inet_pton
1>libcurl.lib(connect.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_inet_pton
1>libcurl.lib(schannel.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_inet_pton
1>libcurl.lib(hostip.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_inet_pton
1>libcurl.lib(ftp.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_inet_pton
1>libcurl.lib(system_win32.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAStartup
1>libcurl.lib(system_win32.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WSACleanup
1>libcurl.lib(rand.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ntohl
1>libcurl.lib(schannel.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertOpenStore
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertOpenStore
1>libcurl.lib(schannel.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertCloseStore
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertCloseStore
1>libcurl.lib(schannel.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertEnumCertificatesInStore
1>libcurl.lib(schannel.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertFindCertificateInStore
1>libcurl.lib(schannel.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertFreeCertificateContext
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertFreeCertificateContext
1>libcurl.lib(schannel.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CryptStringToBinaryA
1>libcurl.lib(schannel.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_PFXImportCertStore
1>libcurl.lib(ftp.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_listen
1>libcurl.lib(socketpair.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_listen
1>libcurl.lib(tftp.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_recvfrom
1>libcurl.lib(tftp.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_sendto
1>libcurl.lib(curl_addrinfo.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_getaddrinfo
1>libcurl.lib(curl_addrinfo.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_freeaddrinfo
1>libcurl.lib(socketpair.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_htonl
1>libcurl.lib(nonblock.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ioctlsocket
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CryptDecodeObjectEx
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertAddCertificateContextToStore
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertFindExtension
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertGetNameStringA
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CryptQueryObject
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertCreateCertificateChainEngine
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertFreeCertificateChainEngine
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertGetCertificateChain
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertFreeCertificateChain
1>libcurl.lib(curl_gethostname.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_gethostname
1>C:\Users\pedro\source\repos\vgm\x64\Release\vgm.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 53 unresolved externals
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Globals part of my `.vcxproject`:

[image: vcxproject]

My Visual Studio's verbosity level (from the solution mentioned):
[image: verbosity]

Output of `vcpkg list`:
[image: vcpkglist]

Type of Runtime Library used:
[image: runtimelib]

I've found a sort of solution [(issue from vcpkg's github)](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/2621) that said I should manually add `Ws2_32.Lib`, `Wldap32.Lib` and `Crypt32.Lib` but I don't know how to do that...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: ***said I should manually add Ws2_32.Lib, Wldap32.Lib and Crypt32.Lib but I don't know how to do that*** You do this in the linker settings. Linker ->Input -> "Additional Dependencies"

Comment: You should not change the runtime of your application. Changing the setting from the default will make the libraries you built with vcpkg not work because for this to work your application and all dependent libraries need to be built with the same runtime.

Comment: @drescherjm thank you this solution worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set your lib directory under Configratuon Properties->VC++ Directories to vcpkg static lib directory. On top of that you need to then link the libs under the Configuration Properties->Linker or using `pragma comment(lib,"libname")`