# Can't run my compiled c++ executable on another machine. Says "libcurl.dll not found"

Tags: c++, curl, static-libraries, libcurl, static-linking

I'm trying to statically link the libcurl library into my executable so I can run my executable on other machines without need of dll files since all the necessary files are baked inside my executable

I've installed curl from vcpkg

```
vcpkg install curl
```

Here are the screenshots of [\include](https://i.imgur.com/QzkuPpj.png) and [\lib](https://i.imgur.com/1vk1L5t.png) folders

Configured my C++ project in Visual Studio to statically link libcurl:

Configuration Properties: [Release]

- C/C++,

  - General, Additional Include Dirs -> `C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include`
  - Preprocessor, Preprocessor Definitions -> `CURL_STATICLIB`
  - Code Generation, Runtime Library -> `Multi-threaded (/MT)`
- Linker:

  - General, Additional Library Dirs -> `C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib`
  - Input, Additional Dependencies -> `libcrypto.lib; libssl.lib; libcurl.lib`

Building the solution in Release mode, Visual Studio compiling it without any issues. Executable runs ok on my machine.

But doesn't run another machine:

```
The code execution cannot proceed because libcurl.dll was not found.
Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.
```

I wonder what I'm doing wrong? Maybe curl cannot be statically combined?
If theres something wrong with my config, then why do other libraries I'm including doesn't raise an error?

---

Also, what other libraries you would recommend for making http requests in c++? I want easy-to-use ones that can be statically compiled into an executable without any issues.

---

#### UPDATE

Reading the [guide](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-statically-link-c-libraries-with-vcpkg-visual-studio-2019-435c2d4ace03) of [@DeanVanGreunen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6651840/dean-van-greunen) posted in the comments of this post, I've realized that I can install `x64-windows-static` versions of packages from `vcpkg`.
So, I've installed `curl:x64-windows-static` which installed the 'static' version of curl into separate `x64-windows-static` folder inside the vcpkg directory.

I configured project solution to link `libcurl.lib` located in the folder. I tried both manual (tweaking the configuration properties) and automatic (bootstapping by `vcpkg integrate install` command and changing the .vcxproj file according to the guide) linking solutions.
Both didn't work, now I can't even build the application!

Here is the build output log: https://pastebin.com/JVx4Z2P4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to statically link VCPKG produced .lib file in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58506430/how-to-statically-link-vcpkg-produced-lib-file-in-visual-studio)

Comment: here is a great [guide](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-statically-link-c-libraries-with-vcpkg-visual-studio-2019-435c2d4ace03)

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen no it doesn't, in his scenario he has "x64-windows-static" directories,  but I haven't. Also I have vcpkg integration turned off for Visual Studio

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen I've followed the guide you've suggested, but it didn't solve the problem. I've updated my post including the outcomes of following that guide

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/2621

Comment: So, to get a single file executable you have to link *all* the libs statically. Not just the first one reported missing.

Comment: @BoP is 100% correct, everything needed needs to be linked, even what is used by the curl dll

Comment: according to your build log you shared the link to, you are missing the curl lib dependancies

Comment: [see this](https://everything.curl.dev/build/deps) for the deps, you will need to link these librarys statically as well, then the build should work fine

Comment: for example this line `libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-bio_sock.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ioctlsocket`  its looking for a socket function/library which is loaded by `libcrypto` so just get all the deps and link them together, good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the [@Alan Birtles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5494370/alan-birtles) for leaving the link to the github/vcpkg issue page in the comments, that solved the problem. I will be leaving step-by-step solution to the problem here for people who face the same issue in the future.

---

### Solution

1. Install `x64-windows-static` versions of packages using `vcpkg`:

   ```
   vcpkg install curl:x64-windows-static
   ```
2. Change `include` and `library` directory paths in configuration properties:

   - from `...\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\...`
   - to `...\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\...`

   ---

   If you have enabled vcpkg integration with Visual Studio, you just need to edit `.vcxproj` file according to the [guide](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-statically-link-c-libraries-with-vcpkg-visual-studio-2019-435c2d4ace03) (thanks to [@Dean Van Greunen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6651840/dean-van-greunen) for suggestion):

   Find `<PropertyGroup Label=”Globals”>` tag and include this inside:

   ```xml
   <VcpkgTriplet Condition="'$(Platform)'=='x64'">x64-windows-static</VcpkgTriplet>
   ```

   And you are ready to go!
3. Link additional neccesary libraries that are needed to successfully link static libraries. You can achieve this using auto-linking in your code:

   ```cpp
   #pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.Lib")
   #pragma comment(lib, "Wldap32.Lib")
   #pragma comment(lib, "Crypt32.Lib")
   ```
4. Compile and enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

If you already succeeded with dynamic linking then your **UPDATE** to static linking is a suitable workaround, but still is not the answer. The professional way is to **keep dynamic linking** as it was and use dlls. You already succeeded to build them dynamically, so keep it this way. There is no need and no good reason to inflate your exe.
First of all, from this `Says "libcurl.dll not found"`, it states explicitly that `libcurl.dll` can't be found. But it is there, in the place where libcurl is installed. So, make the dlls visible to your application. In the place where libcurl is installed, find the directory containing libcurl.dll, for instance it is located here `c:\path\libcurl\dlls`, maybe somewhere else. Now you choose one of **Option**s which is best to you.
**Option 1**, before launching your application, update the system path, it is ";" separated

```
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\path\libcurl\dlls
yourapplication.exe #now it should not fail
```

**Option 2**, in Windows Settings search for System Variables and open the Edit System Environment Variables
[image]
Click environment variables and add your dll path to Path
[image]
You can add it to User path if you want it to be visible only under your user, or to System path if you want it to be visible for all users. Windows merges the two Path variables before running an application. Now you will be able to run your application.
**Option 3** Don't alter path, but place your curl dll files into some place where your path already points. Now you will be able to run your application.
**Option 4** Place your dll files in the same folder with your compiled exe file. Now you will be able to run your application.
**Option 5** Make it visible to your IDE, for instance if it is VisualStudio, open the project properties, then in Debugging Options add your variable Path, inherit it from System Defaults, then add path to dlls there. Then you will be able to run it from your IDE
[image]
**Option 6** If you want to distribute your application, package it with copies of curl and other dll files, in the same folder with your exe. Now you will be able to run your application on a different computer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I mentioned in the post, the compiled executable was working fine without any issues on my local machine, but was not working when I try to run it on another machine. So, I wanted to compile all the deps into a single executable. Surely I could dynamically link those libs, but I would have needed to copy all the dlls into another machine to work, which is not convenient.

Comment: @GooDeeJAY As I mentioned at the end, you should distribute with the dlls, because this is the expert way to do it. Keep it dynamic. There is absolutely no reason to inflate your exe.

Comment: ***So, I wanted to compile all the deps into a single executable. Surely I could dynamically link those libs, but I would have needed to copy all the dlls into another machine to work, which is not convenient.*** You could create an installer for your application like most commercial software does. NSIS or WiX are good choices.

Comment: @GooDeeJAY You can package it as a zip, as many authors like Apache, Perl, Python, even Curl already do. Better get familiar with it. The statically inflated exe will not be better in any way. It will not start faster, it will not run faster, it will not save disk space. Dynamic linking is always the best option over statical linking, when provided.